# Does a Carmichael number with $k$ prime factors exist for every $k\ge 3$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Here

https://oeis.org/search?q=carmichael+number+factors&language=german&go=Suche

the smallest Carmichael numbers with $k=3,...,35$ prime factors are shown. In Wikipdia,
it is stated, that a Carmichael number with over $1,000,000$ prime factors has been constructed.

> Is there a Carmichael number with $k$ prime factors for every $k\ge 3$ ?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number#Discovery)  says a Carmichael number with over 16 million digits and $1,101,518$ factors was found.  It also states that there are at least $n^{2/7}$ Carmichael numbers less than $n$  I would expect that this means there are Carmichael numbers with arbitrarily many factors.  That certainly leaves open the possibility that there is some number of factors not represented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an open problem, as mentioned in Richard Guy's Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, 2004 edition, as well as the paper "Carmichael numbers with three prime factors" by Heath-Brown in 2007. An even more recent paper that mentions its status as open is "Constructing Carmichael numbers through improved subset-product algorithms" by Alford, Grantham, Hayman, and Shallue, in 2013.